# How to append a char to the end of a string [Try to Keep it Simple please] - [Arduino]

Tags: c++, string, arduino, char, passwords

ps: I’m sorry I turns out everything works fine it didn’t work for me because I was using a constant char array but I’m not sure how to fix it

I am new to Arduino and I'm trying to make a passcode lock using:

Servo Motor: x1

LCD Screen 16x2: x1

4x4 Keypad: x1

Bread board: x1

Arduino Mega 2560: x1

and I ran into a problem that I cant combine a String and a Char
because it replaces the string with the char for example:

```
String String1 = "Hello I like doughnut";
Char Char1 = "s";

String1 = String1 + char1;

Output: S
```

What I tried and didn't work:

Using .append from password library.
trying to use `concat();`

I also tried using a password library so I can use .append but I want to be able to enter the passcode on screen such as:
Enter Password:
1234

And it doesn't allow you to do it with  an LCD screen. Any help would be Appreciate.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. `String1 = String1 + char1;` should work if `String1` is a `std::string` and `char1` is a `char`, though `"s"` is not a character literal

Comment: What is the type of `String1`? Probably an arduino `String` right?

Comment: Yes it’s an Arduino String. And I don’t really know how to answer the first question. @JohnFilleau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define as follows:

```
String String1 = "Hello I like doughnut";
String Char1 = "s";

 String1 = String1 + Char1; // WORKS
```

This would be a char

```
 char Char1 = 's';
```

And as an extra tip: Get rid of Strings and learn how to handle char arrays - it will save you a lot of headache later on. Google for "The evil of Strings" and read it.

Comment: The combination didn’t work for me but I’ll try to research about char arrays as it sounds as the right thing to use in this situation

Comment: It worked I researched about the evil or strings aswell it helped allot thanks